# tailwind css not working properly in nextjs

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I am working with tailwind in Next.js and I create the environment using this command: [npx create-next-app --example with-tailwindcss with-tailwindcss-app](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss)

Everything works fine except one thing

- I am using breakpoints on `<span/>` tag
  if I use all breakpoints except default(xs) then my design works fine but if is use default breakpoint with other breakpoints then the default/xs applies to every other breakpoint.

```
 <span className=" text-xl text-red-500  sm:text-blue-500 md:text-indigo-500 lg:text-violet-500 font-semibold  "> Hy, I am </span>
```

**In my code `text-red-500` applies to every breakpoint**

I know my syntax is correct, but somehow there is a problem in loading my CSS files and I don't have any idea which files should I have to target.

everybody's opinion is acceptable

I have also attached some of the files in my project.

[image: tailwind.config][image: package.json][image: global.css][image: app.js]

Comment: Maybe try to initialize your project as recommended by tailwindcss ? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Comment: Please do not post images of code, anything text-based should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case the problem was, that i had wrong paths in **tailwind.config.js**:

Before:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Fixed:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

You should specify a path relative to tailwind.config.js

Answer (score 1):

on `globals.css` file

before

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

try this

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated the same project with the same versions of tailwind and other dependencies. It works fine for me.
Can you please try to upgrade tailwind to the latest version using `npm install tailwindcss@latest`

**OR**

I noticed one typo in your `globals.css` file. You have missed closing curley brackets for

```
@layer components {

}
```

Your CSS file should be giving an error for this. Try fixing it, if it helps.

Comment: no sorry @layer components{} is good  just missed the bracket while taking the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

**material-tailwind** is being used in this project. In `_app.js` you should arrange the imports according to the sequence given in the [material-tailwind documentation](https://material-tailwind.com/documentation/quick-start#:%7E:text=Make%20sure%20to%20import%20the%20tailwind.css%20style%20sheet%20after%20all%20other%20style%20sheets.)

example

```
// before >>> wrong approach

import "../styles/globals.css";
import Head from "next/head";
import "@material-tailwind/react/tailwind.css";


// after >>> valid approach

import Head from "next/head";
import "@material-tailwind/react/tailwind.css";
import "../styles/globals.css";
```

and the design will work properly

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this issue for ages and these answers didn't help as I would *sometimes* see the tailwind color class working, other times not.

My issue was that I was dynamically rendering my classes

i.e. `bg-${class}-{shade}` (e.g.`class=red` and `shade=900` renders `bg-red-900`)

Apparently you can't do that. [Nextjs can not render all the Tailwind css Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74101471/nextjs-can-not-render-all-the-tailwind-css-colors)